# Inverse and extension of the $n$th Airy Ai and Bi zero

Tags: roots, inverse-function, analytic-continuation, meromorphic-functions, airy-functions

$\def\ai{\operatorname{ai}} \def\bi{\operatorname{bi}} \def\Ai{\operatorname{Ai}} \def\Bi{\operatorname{Bi}} $ [**Airy Ai Zero** $\ai_n$](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/AiryAiZero/02/) gives the $n$th zero of the [Airy Ai](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=AiryAi) function and [**Airy Bi Zero** $\bi_n$](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/AiryBiZero/) of [Airy Bi](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=AiryBi). The analytic continuation of $\ai_n,\bi_n$ use [Bessel J Zero $j_{v,x}$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselJZero.html), and [Bessel Y Zero $y_{v,x}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=BesselYZero)

$$-\left(\frac32j_{\frac13,n-\frac16}\right)^\frac23=\ai_n,n\in\Bbb N$$ [image] [image] [shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-%283%2F2+besseljzero%281%2F3%2C3-1%2F6%29%29%5E%282%2F3%29-airyaizero%283%29) and $$-\left(\frac32 y_{\frac13,n-\frac16}\right)^\frac23=\bi_n,n\in\Bbb N$$ [image] [image] [shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-%283%2F2+besselyzero%281%2F3%2C43-1%2F6%29%29%5E%282%2F3%29-airybizero%2843%29).

Using our extensions, we find that “$\ai_{x-\frac12}=\bi_x$“, so we ignore $\bi_n$‘s inverse for now. Now [invert](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493772/what-does-the-3d-plot-of-z-textbesselyzerox-y-look-like)  the extensions using [DLMF 9.9ii](https://dlmf.nist.gov/9.9#ii) and the [**Airy Phase function** $\theta(x)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/9.8#E4):

$$-\left(\frac32j_{\frac13,\frac{\theta(x)}\pi+n-\frac16}\right)^\frac23=x;\bi_n<x<\bi_{n+1}, n\in\Bbb N, $$

Unfortunately, $\frac{\theta(x)}\pi=\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\Ai(x)}{\Bi(x)}\right)}\pi$ has discontinuities at the aforementioned $\bi_n$:

[image]$\tag1$

There cannot be a left inverse of the discrete $\ai_n,n\in\Bbb N$ and [approximations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%283+%CF%80+%2B+8+%28-airyaizero%28x%29%29%5E%283%2F2%29%29%2F%2812+%CF%80%29-x) for it are not the right inverse. On the other hand, if one [superimposes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28atan%28Ai%28x%29%2FBi%28x%29%29%2Fpi-y%29%28atan%28Ai%28x%29%2FBi%28x%29%29%2Fpi%2B1-y%29%28atan%28Ai%28x%29%2FBi%28x%29%29%2Fpi%2B2-y%29%28atan%28Ai%28x%29%2FBi%28x%29%29%2Fpi%2B3-y%29%3D0+%2C-6%3Cx%3C2%2C+-1%3Cy%3C4) $\frac{\theta(x)}\pi+n,n\in\Bbb N$, then we want the highlighted branch which will give the [right](https://people.math.carleton.ca/%7Ekcheung/math/notes/MATH1107/wk06/06_left_and_right_inverses.html) and most accurate [left](https://people.math.carleton.ca/%7Ekcheung/math/notes/MATH1107/wk06/06_left_and_right_inverses.html) inverse for $\ai_n$.

[image] $\tag2$

The piecewise function for the highlighted graph is:

$$\cases{\frac{\theta(x)}\pi,x>\bi_1\\ \frac{\theta(x)}\pi+1, \bi_1<x<\bi_2\\\frac{\theta(x)}\pi+2, \bi_2<x<\bi_3\\\rule{13.65mm}{0ex} \vdots\\\frac{\theta(x)}\pi+n, \bi_n<x<\bi_n}$$

but it is unwieldy. What is an equation for $(2)$’s highlighted graph given $(1)$? It could be a [meromorphic extension](https://planetmath.org/meromorphicextension).

The DLMF [Airy Modulus function $\text M(x)=\sqrt{\Ai^2(x)+\Bi^2(x)}$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/9.9#ii)  appears after differentiating:

$$\begin{align}\frac d{dx}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\Ai(x)}{\Bi(x)}\right)=-\frac1{\pi\left(\Ai^2(x)+\Bi^2(x)\right)}\implies \frac{\theta(x)}\pi\text{ without discontinuities}=-\frac1\pi\int\frac{dx}{\Ai^2(x)+\Bi^2(x)}=-\frac1\pi\int  \text M^{-2}(x)dx\end{align}$$

The graph of the derivative has no discontinuities, but how does one integrate it so there are none afterwards?

[image]

Comment: One more Nice problem

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks. Do you have any ideas on it?